# Safari does not update textPath when path data is changed dynamically

Tags: svg, safari

I have a path which I'm referencing from a `textPath` element in SVG, I'm updating the path data dynamically. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but Safari (v16.1) is not updating the `textPath` to reflect the updated path data.

Here is the stripped down use case:

```js
const path = document.querySelector("path");
setInterval(function(){
  path.setAttribute("d", `M ${Math.random()*20} ${Math.random()*400} C 11 195 385 105 789 227`)
}, 100);
```

```html
<svg width="800" height="400" viewBox="0 0 800 400">
  <text>
     <textPath text-anchor="middle" startOffset="50%" href="#tp-path" font-size="51" font-family="sans-serif">Lorem Ipsum</textPath>
   </text>
   <path d="M 22 400 C 11 195 385 105 789 227" fill="none" stroke="#ccc" id="tp-path"></path>
 </svg>
```

Seems like a bug to me, any help working around it would be appreciated.

Comment: report it to https://bugs.webkit.org/ unless it's already been reported.

Comment: @RobertLongson not familiar with reporting bugs to browser vendors but left a comment at the bottom of this very old bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15799

Answer (score 0):

I found one workaround: if I add the `href` attribute dynamically it will work in Safari:

```js
const path = document.querySelector("path");
const textPath = document.querySelector("textPath");
textPath.setAttribute("href", "#tp-path");
setInterval(function(){
  path.setAttribute("d", `M ${Math.random()*20} ${Math.random()*400} C 11 195 385 105 789 227`)
}, 100);
```

```html
<svg width="800" height="400" viewBox="0 0 800 400">
  <text>
     <textPath text-anchor="middle" startOffset="50%" font-size="51" font-family="sans-serif">Lorem Ipsum</textPath>
   </text>
   <path d="M 22 400 C 11 195 385 105 789 227" fill="none" stroke="#ccc" id="tp-path"></path>
 </svg>
```